# Using WPF and SlimDx (DirectX 10/11)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directx, slimdx

I am using SlimDX with WinForms for a while now, but want to make the switch to WPF now. However, I can't figure out how to get DX10/11 working with WPF. The February release of SlimDX provides a WPF example, which only works with DX 9 though. 
I found the following solution: http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/437/Direct3D-10-11-Direct2D-in-WPF.aspx
but can't get it to work with SlimDX. My main problem is the shared resource handle as I don't know how to retrieve the shared handle from a SlimDX texture. I can't find any information to this topic.

In C++ the code looks like this:

```
HRESULT D3DImageEx::GetSharedHandle(IUnknown *pUnknown, HANDLE * pHandle)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    *pHandle = NULL;
    IDXGIResource* pSurface;

    if (FAILED(hr = pUnknown->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&pSurface)))
        return hr;

    hr = pSurface->GetSharedHandle(pHandle);
    pSurface->Release();

    return hr;
}
```

Basically, what I want to do (because I think that this is the solution), is to share a texture between a Direct3d9DeviceEx (for rendering the WPF D3DImage) and a Direct3d10Device (a texture render target for my scene).

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They posted some sample code on how to use slimdx/directx10 with WPF.  Here's the [link](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/browse/trunk/samples/Direct3D10/WpfSample10/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a control called WindowsFormsHost, maybe you could integrate your current WinForm control that way?

Comment: That works, however it does not integrate nicely with WPF. The WinForms control must be on top, can not be overlayed with other WPF controls etc.

However, I managed to get DX10/WPF running nicely. I couldn't figure out if GetSharedHandle was available in SlimDX, so I checked out the source code and added some C++ code to provide me with the needed functionality.
If I can find the time, I will post and update and explain my solution in some detail.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at D3DImageEx. http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/437/Direct3D-10-11-Direct2D-in-WPF.aspx
You provide a reference to your rendertarget, but it has to be created with the Shared flag. I was not able to use a swapchain in this way though.

```
let renderTargetDescription = Texture2DDescription(     Width=width,
                                                        Height=height,
                                                        MipLevels=1,
                                                        ArraySize=1,
                                                        Format = Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm,
                                                        SampleDescription = SampleDescription(Count = 1),
                                                        BindFlags = (BindFlags.RenderTarget ||| BindFlags.ShaderResource),
                                                        OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.Shared)
```

Comment: I posted the same link in my question above, unfortunately it does provide a solution to my problem.